# One by one addEventListener collision

Tags: sdk, lua, collision-detection, coronasdk, game-engine

I'm working on a simple breakout game and I've problem with `ball:addEventListener( "collision", removeBricks )`, it works fine until the ball hits two bricks at same time, than the up/down direction (`vy`) switch twice, making the ball continue moving up or down.

How can do one by one addEventListener collision and disable multiple collides at once?

```
function removeBricks(event)

    if event.other.isBrick == 1 then
        vy = vy * (-1)  
        ...
    end
end
```

Comment: can you provide further code on how you create the brick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of changing ball's velocity in the `removeBricks` function, you can just flip a flag that means "a ball has hit some bricks and should change it's direction", and then in your `enterFrame` handler just change the ball's speed:

```
local ballHasCollided = false

local function removeBricks(event)
    if event.other.isBrick == 1 then
        ballHasCollided = true
    end
end

local function updateBallVelocity(event)
    if ballHasCollided then
        ballHasCollided = false
        ball.vy = -ball.vy
        -- ...
end

-- your game set up code somewhere
Runtime:addEventListener('enterFrame', updateBallVelocity)
```